# postgresql initdb.exe option flags not working in command line

Tags: postgresql, command-line

in `cmd.exe` command line i go to the directory where there's `initdb.exe` and then i run :

`initdb.exe -D "C:/data/" -U postgres -E UTF8`

then the database is created with this message (in french, but i translated it in english for here) :

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "MyComputerUserName".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "French_France.1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "french".
```

My problem is that the command line flag for the user is not set to `postgres` and i get a `1252` Encoding instead of `utf8`.
But for a strange reason, the directoty flag work well and the `data` directory is created.

i tried to launch cmd.exe either with or without admin rights, but i get the same problem.

i use the version `postgresql-13.1-1-windows-x64-binaries`

any ideas on why the command line not working correctly? (´･ω･`)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here (or at least, no evidence of it).  -U controls the name of the boot-strap superuser within PostgreSQL, while the message tells you the name of the OS user who will own the files.  It is not a contradiction for those to be different.

UTF8 is an encoding, while "French_France.1252" is a locale.  Again, it is not a contradiction for those to be different.  Indeed they have to be different, as there is no locale named 'UTF8'.

If you start up the database, I think you will find that the superuser's name is postgres the encoding is UTF8.

Comment: It should be noted that that applies only to Windows. On other operating systems, the locale must match the encoding.